# Greater touch area on custom keyboard UIButtons

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, area

I am putting together a custom keyboard for practice, and I am trying to give the keyboard buttons a greater touch area like they have with the default iOS keyboard.

The image below shows the keyboard buttons and the extended touch area that I want to add:
[image]

I have already tried adding contentEdgeInsets but the padding that it creates is not touchable, and it also messes up the alignment of the button labels since the buttons are not images.

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not exactly. However, instead I simply created a CGRect for each UIButton. Not exactly a very effective approach.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer with some sample code?